# What is the default datatype for the emotions dataset (one of huggingface's site dataset)?

Tags: python, formatting, format, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I'm working with the emotions dataset from HuggingFace library.

I know I can switch its presentation format to pandas by doing:

```
emotions.set_format(type='pandas')
```

And I can switch it back to its default presentation format by doing:

```
emotions.reset_format()
```

My doubts are two: 1st) what types are allowed besides 'pandas'? and 2nd) what is the name of the default format? I tried looking on internet and on some books but found nothing.

Comment: Does it answer your question: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.set_format

Comment: Well, yes. So it's `None` which means "standard Python objects". So I can say that if I do `.set_format(type=None)` it will be the same as `.reset_format()`.